# Issue in loading html page after navigating from a geolocation page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

i am working on javascript and jquery. and i have created 2 pages, the 1 will generae a map view of the current location and if we click our current location it will navigate to the next page which will find the lat and long of the user and generates a weather report. but both the pages work fine seperately but when integrated the map view is generated but when the weather link is clicked the page does not get loaded. Any suggesions or help would be appreciated. i have even fiddled http://jsfiddle.net/mJgdz/ my weather page's code and pasted my geolocation code below:

My HTML gelocation code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <title>Getting Geolocation for Weather Details</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
  }

  @media print {
    html, body {
      height: auto;
    }

    #map_canvas {
      height: 650px;
    }
  }
    </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var map;

    function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

      // Try HTML5 geolocation
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: '<a href="weatherdetails.html">click here for weather details</a>'
          });

          map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
         });
        } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
       }
      }

      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
         if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
      content: content
       };

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
       map.setCenter(options.position);
     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your fiddle has this javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined`

Comment: @geocodezip: but it works fine with in eclispe.

Comment: I didn't try it in eclipse.

Comment: @geocodezip: i am sure the when i open only the weather page it works fine but when i integrate with my project with as usual a href="weather.html" tag does not make it work. it navigates but not loads